# Regular expression for yyyy mm dd hh mm ss (no punctuation) in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression for datetime. The problem is that my strings have no punctuation, so rather than having the information as follows yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, it is like this **yyyy mm dd hh mm ss**.

Do you know a regular expression which matches this format?

Comment: Thank you all, I finally got it work with: (19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}) ((0(1|3|5|7|8)|10|12) (0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])|(0(4|6|9)|11) (0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)|(02) (0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))\x20(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])( [0-5][0-9]){2}

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strptime` to convert to `POSIXt`:

```
strptime("1982 03 17 05 24 54", "%Y %m %d %H %M %S")
#output
[1] "1982-03-17 05:24:54 CET"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use \\d{n} where n would be number of digits. Example:

```
grepl("\\d{4} \\d{2} \\d{2} \\d{2} \\d{2} \\d{2}", "1995 04 30 10 15 00")

[1] TRUE
```

You can also use \\s for space

```
grepl("\\d{4}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}", "1995 04 30 10 15 00")

[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The format showed can be automatically picked with `anytime`

```
anytime::anytime("1982 03 17 05 24 54")
#[1] "1982-03-17 05:24:54 EST"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression itself is very easy.

```
(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2})
```

It just matches digits a certain amount of times (either 4 for years or 2 for the rest).

The other thing is, that you don't have a time from this, but plain strings which then you have to convert to a date. I suggest you to use other functions/tools as regular expressions.

Comment: Why using capture groups?

Comment: To capture the groups ;) So can leave them if you want, if you only want to **match** it,instead of having the information

Answer (score 0):

Add start ^ and end $ anchors to  regex.

```
(preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/"))
```

Comment: Why using capture groups?

Answer (score 0):

One way is, you can replace empty spaces with '-' or '/' and try regExp again. Hope it helps.

```
        var stringDate = '2018 8 29 09 09 09';
        var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{4} (3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]) (1[0- 
                       2]|0[1-9]) (2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]) ([0-5]?[0-9]) ([0-5]?[0-9])$");

        if (stringDate.search(pattern) === 0) {
            return true;
        }
```

Here, this pattern will work for your formats of date. Hope it helps now :)

Comment: could you provide the reason behind replacing " " with "-" and the code to do so? I trust it will improve your answer.